# Magento 'Sort By' defaulting to price

Tags: magento-1.9

We are building a website for a client and are towards the end of the build.

We have been stuck with a problem of the product 'sort by' ordering being stuck on price ascending. We've attempted to override it on the Manage Categories section, via System>Configuration too, but it will only default to price ASC.

Even if we select Name or Date on the front end, it won't change from Price ASC.

Could anyone shed some light on to this? Magento 1.9.1 using RWD theme

Comment: So, what do you want your default sort order?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for us, although right now it is not working so something due to the code?

Our site is under development. I am a store admin, not a coder. 
We were able to go through our categories and change the default sort order there manually.  In our case we want our products sorted by Name so they sort alphabetically. We ended up going  through every category and updated this. I'm not sure if we had changed the default sort BEFORE creating a lot of categories if that would have worked out differently.

Overall default:
System> Configuration> Catalog
Product Listing Sort by:

By category:
Catalog> Manage Categories
Display Setting tab
Available Product Listing Sort By: "Name"
Default Product Listing Sort By: "Name"

HTH